# Drop/delete remote commits from branch

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-remote

After rebasing and dropping/using fixup on a few commits from my branch locally, I noticed that there are 4 commits on the pull request that I can't find locally.  How do I get rid of those?

Comment: You could try to find and delete them in the reflog, however there is not necessarily any need for this.  Orphaned commits not being used by any branches should be garbage collected automatically without your intervention.

Answer (score 1):

A force push (aka `git push --force`) should clean them up.